# Java AVL Tree updating size efficiently

Tags: java, recursion

Currently I have managed to get all 4 cases of rotation code right. My problem now is to get words that are in a range defined by the system. It is inclusive of start and exclusive of end stop words provided by the system.

The method I am using to get the total numbers of words is working correctly as I am using a `nodeSize` method whereby it is the addition of both left and right subtree and itself [left subtree+rightsubtree+1].The difference or number of words in a range is obtained as there are overlap points for both start and end stop words.

What I am using to update for all nodes sizes in an AVL tree is to implement `nodeSize` method in an inorder method. This works fine as i have checked earlier for small range details. The only issue now I encounter how to make it more time efficient when there are over 10,000 nodes in the tree and over 5000 queries for it.

```
public int nodeSize(BSTVertex T) {
    if (T == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return nodeSize(T.left) + nodeSize(T.right) + 1;
    }
}

public void insert(String v) {
    root = insert(root, v);
}

protected BSTVertex insert(BSTVertex T, String v) {
    if (T == null) {
        return new BSTVertex(v);
    }
    if (T.key.compareTo(v) < 0) {
        T.right = insert(T.right, v);
        T.right.parent = T;
    } else {// search to the left
        T.left = insert(T.left, v);
        T.left.parent = T;
    }
    T.totalNode = nodeSize(T);
    int balance = nodeHeight(T.left) - nodeHeight(T.right);
    if (balance == 2) {
        int balance2 = nodeHeight(T.left.left) - nodeHeight(T.left.right);
        if (balance2 == 1) {
            T = rightRotation(T);
        } else {//Left Right Case  2,-1
            T.left = rotateLeft(T.left);
            T = rightRotation(T);
        }
    }

    if (balance == -2) {
        int balance2 = nodeHeight(T.right.left) - nodeHeight(T.right.right);
        if (balance2 == -1) {
            T = rotateLeft(T);  //single left for -1
        } else {//Right left case, -2,1
            T.right = rightRotation(T.right);
            T = rotateLeft(T);
        }
    }
    inorder(T);
    return T;
}
```